# Getting error while creating Entity classes with multiple relationships in SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create Entity classes for a sample movie ticket booking application. Please find the entity classes with their association mapping below
Please notice that ShowSeatReservation has composite key.

```java
@Entity
@Table (name = "Booking")
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "booking_id")
    private long id;

    //@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JoinColumn (name = "show_id")
    //private Show show;

    private String userName;
    private String movieName;
    private String theaterName;
    private Date showTime;

}


public enum BookingStatus {
    CREATED,
    EXPIRED,
    RESERVED
}

@Entity
@Table (name = "movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "movie_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String certificateNumber;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table (name = "Screen")
public class Screen {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "screen_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "theater_id")
    private Theater theater;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "screen", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Show> shows;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "screen", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Seat> seats;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Seat")
public class Seat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "seat_id")
    private long id;
    @NonNull
    private int rowNumber;
    @NonNull
    private int colNumber;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "screen_id")
    private Screen screen;


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Show")
public class Show {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "show_id")
    private long id;

    private Date showTime;
    private int playTime;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "screen_id")
    private Screen screen;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "theater_id")
    private Theater theater;

    }



@Entity
@Table(name = "show_seat_reservation")
@IdClass(ShowSeatReservationId.class)
public class ShowSeatReservation {
    @Id
    private long showId;
    @Id
    private long seatId;

    private BookingStatus bookingStatus;
    private Date bookingTime;
    private int expiryTime;
    private String movieName;
    private int row;
    private int col;
}

@Entity
@Table (name = "Theater")
public class Theater {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "theater_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "theater",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Screen> screens;
    
}


public class ShowSeatReservationId implements Serializable {
    private long showId;
    private long seatId;

    public ShowSeatReservationId() {
    }

    public ShowSeatReservationId(long showId, long seatId) {
        this.showId = showId;
        this.seatId = seatId;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ShowSeatReservationId that = (ShowSeatReservationId) o;
        return showId == that.showId && seatId == that.seatId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(showId, seatId);
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run my springboot application, I am getting below error

```java
create table seat (
       seat_id bigint not null,
        col_number integer not null,
        row_number integer not null,
        screen_id bigint,
        primary key (seat_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2022-09-05 01:05:03.857  WARN 27112 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table seat (
       seat_id bigint not null,
        col_number integer not null,
        row_number integer not null,
        screen_id bigint,
        primary key (seat_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table seat (
       seat_id bigint not null,
        col_number integer not null,
        row_number integer not null,
        screen_id bigint,
        primary key (seat_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.mappingexample.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'row_number integer not null,
        screen_id bigint,
        primary key (se' at line 4
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

Hibernate: 
    
    create table show (
       show_id bigint not null,
        play_time integer not null,
        show_time datetime(6),
        movie_id bigint,
        screen_id bigint,
        theater_id bigint,
        primary key (show_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2022-09-05 01:05:03.861  WARN 27112 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table show (
       show_id bigint not null,
        play_time integer not null,
        show_time datetime(6),
        movie_id bigint,
        screen_id bigint,
        theater_id bigint,
        primary key (show_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table show (
       show_id bigint not null,
        play_time integer not null,
        show_time datetime(6),
        movie_id bigint,
        screen_id bigint,
        theater_id bigint,
        primary key (show_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.mappingexample.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show (
       show_id bigint not null,
        play_time integer not null,
  ' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Find full error in link [full error](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/8b1476d0-d528-493c-be7d-95b5ff21a405)

I am getting error for Entity Seat and Show and ShowSeatReservation table. Rest tables are getting created in mysql database.

[image: Database tables]

Please help why I am getting errors.
Please suggest correct code also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked too much at your code, but a cursory glance seems to look ok.  From your stack trace, the error that you're getting is from your DDL.  Looking at the error, I can see that you're using MySQL.  You need to know that `show` is a reserved word in MySQL, you cannot create a table named `show`.

Comment: hi @lane.maxwell, great observation. I was getting error for show table, seat tables. I changed their names to MovieShow and ScreenSeat and now it is working just fine.